# onClick event in nested elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I click on the div that includes the AnimatedMouse component the event that logged in the console is one of the elements of AnimatedMouse component not the div with className "animated-mouse" itself.

```js
const AnimatedMouseScroll = () => {
    return (
        <div class="scroll-msg-container">
            <div class="scroll-msg-inner">
                <div class="scroll-msg-wheel">
                    click here
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

const EmployerService = () => {
    const scrollToNextSectionHandler = (event) => {
        console.log("clicked element", event.target)
    };

    return (
        <div className="animated-mouse" onClick={(e) => scrollToNextSectionHandler(e)}>
            <AnimatedMouseScroll />
        </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<EmployerService />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.10.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.10.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You haven't included `AnimatedMouse`. You've included `AnimatedMouseScroll`, but not `AnimatedMouse`. I've turned your code blocks into a Stack Snippet (the `[<>]` toolbar button) and changed `AnimatedMouse` to `AnimatedMouseScroll` and it seems to show what you're trying to show. For next time, [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). Runnable examples help you ensure you've included everything necessary, and make it much easier for people to help you.

Comment: try onClick={(e)=> {e.stopPropagation(); scrollToNextSectionHandler(e);}}

Comment: @ArshpreetWadehra - That won't make any difference at all.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I made a mistake in copy and paste the code, but in the real project, everything is ok.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`target` is always the innermost target element that was clicked. (This is true in the DOM, not just React.) If you want the element you've put the event handler on, use `currentTarget`:

```
console.log("clicked element", event.currentTarget )
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^
```

Live Example:

```js
const AnimatedMouseScroll = () => {
 return (
       <div class="scroll-msg-container">
       <div class="scroll-msg-inner"  >
       <div class= "scroll-msg-wheel" >
       click here
       </div>
       </div>
       </div>
       );
}

const EmployerService = () => {
    const scrollToNextSectionHandler = (event) => {
   console.log("clicked element", event.currentTarget )
    };

  return (
      <div  className="animated-mouse"  onClick={(e) => scrollToNextSectionHandler(e)}>
    <AnimatedMouseScroll />
  </div>
       );
}

ReactDOM.render(<EmployerService/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.10.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.10.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @s.hesam - No worries!